# Cumulativ sums of subset of columns in data.table using .SD

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a data.table with a couple of IDs and a long list of numerical columns that represent probabities that add up to one for each row. Minimal example:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(
  ID = c("a","b","c"),
  ProbA = c(0.6, 0.25, 0.55),
  ProbB = c(0.25, 0.55, 0.35),
  ProbC = c(0.15, 0.2, 0.1)
);DT

   ID ProbA ProbB ProbC
1:  a  0.60  0.25  0.15
2:  b  0.25  0.55  0.20
3:  c  0.55  0.35  0.10
```

Now I want to add columns for each of the probabilities with the cumulative probabities with respect to their column index, like so:

```
  ID ProbA ProbB ProbC ProbAcum ProbBcum ProbCcum
1:  a  0.60  0.25  0.15     0.60     0.85        1
2:  b  0.25  0.55  0.20     0.25     0.80        1
3:  c  0.55  0.35  0.10     0.55     0.90        1
```

I've tried it with `lapply` and subsetting the columns:

```
Probcols <- c("ProbA", "ProbB", "ProbC")
DT[, (paste0(Probcols,"cum")):=lapply(.SD, function(x){rowSums(DT[, 2:which(Probcols==x)])}), .SDcols=Probcols]
```

can I make that work somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (I am using a Base R approach):

```
do.call('cbind', Reduce(`+`, DT[,2:4], accumulate = TRUE))
```

Using Reduce with accumulate = TRUE does the accumulation part, all you have to care that the columns which you select here should be numeric for example I took 2:4 for selecting numeric column only

You can do a cbind it with existing dataframe:

```
cbind(DT, do.call('cbind', Reduce(`+`, DT[,2:4], accumulate = TRUE))
```

> ```
> do.call('cbind', Reduce(`+`, DT[,2:4], accumulate = TRUE))
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,] 0.60 0.85    1
> [2,] 0.25 0.80    1
> [3,] 0.55 0.90    1
> ```

In case you keep the names as is:

```
nm1 <- names(DT)
nm2 <- paste0(names(DT)[-1], '_Accum')
DT <- cbind(DT, do.call('cbind', Reduce(`+`, DT[,2:4], accumulate = TRUE)))
names(DT) <- c(nm1,nm2)
```

**OR**  using  data.table approach, taking original `DT` and `nm2 <- paste0(names(DT)[-1], '_Accum')`

```
DT[, c(nm2) := Reduce(`+`, .SD[,2:4], accumulate = TRUE)]
```

**Ouput**:

> ```
>   ID ProbA ProbB ProbC ProbA_Accum ProbB_Accum ProbC_Accum
> 1:  a  0.60  0.25  0.15        0.60        0.85           1
> 2:  b  0.25  0.55  0.20        0.25        0.80           1
> 3:  c  0.55  0.35  0.10        0.55        0.90           1
> >
> ```

Answer (score 2):

One option with `rowCumsums`

```
library(matrixStats)    
DT[, paste0(names(DT)[-1], "Accum"):= asplit(rowCumsums(as.matrix(.SD[, 
      -1, with = FALSE])), 2)]
DT
#   ID ProbA ProbB ProbC ProbAAccum ProbBAccum ProbCAccum
#1:  a  0.60  0.25  0.15       0.60       0.85          1
#2:  b  0.25  0.55  0.20       0.25       0.80          1
#3:  c  0.55  0.35  0.10       0.55       0.90          1
```